# Perform subtraction micro operation R3←R1-R2 where R1=1011 and R2=1100

Tags: computer-architecture

From tutorials point:

> Subtract micro-operation are using minus operator we create 1's complement and add 1 to the register which obtains subtracted, i.e R1 - R2 is similar to R3 → R1 + R2' + 1

$$
R2'= 0011
$$

$$
R3=R1+R2'+1
\\\Rightarrow R3 = 1011+0011+1
\\\Rightarrow R3 = 1111 
$$

This is obviously not the right answer, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is it "obviously" not the right answer ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust 1111 isn't -1?

Comment: You don't answer my question. And you did not read my answer, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, $(-5)-(-4)=-1$ is correct.

Comment: But 1111 isn't -1?